# argparse - python

Tags: python, argparse

In a python script I want to have three positional arguments and two optional arguments(including 'help'). So my need is like following

Correct:

```
./myscript.py ONE TWO THREE
./myscript.py --list
```

Incorrect:

```
./myscript.py ONE TWO THREE --list
```

I want to make all positional argument and the optional argument as mutual exclusive using argparse itself.

Comment: Hello. Your question is off-topic for ServerFault and would likely be better to StackOverflow which is more coding-based.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/argparse.html#id1

Comment: I made the solution using conditions. As far as I understand, there is no possible way to do it using argparse itself. Current version of argparse supports mutual exclusive option only for one condition. Like [A|B] and not [A,B,C | D]

Comment: Missing minimal working example.

Answer (score 2):

This approxmates what you want:

```
class Three(argparse.Action):
    # custom action that requires 0 or 3 values
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string):
        if len(values) in [0,3]:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
        else:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self,'must have 3 values')

custom = 'usage: %(prog)s [-h] (--list | ONE TWO THREE)'
p=argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG',usage=custom)
g=p.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
g.add_argument('--list',action='store_true')
g.add_argument('pos',nargs='*',default=[],action=Three)
```

It raises an error if both `--list` and `pos` are given, if nothing is given, or the number of `pos` values is not 3.  I included a custom usage since the default is:

```
usage: PROG [-h] (--list | pos [pos ...])
```